# Element ordering for cache-friendly 2D arrays

Tags: arrays, optimization, data-structures

Is there a way to arrange the elements in a 2D array (1D array with size width * height, [y*width+x] for access), so that small cartesian distances tend to translate into 1D indices that are close together? I need to do a random walk through a 2D array and want to optimize for cache-friendliness.

Answer (score 2):

A space-filling-curve reduces the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity. There are for example z-curve, hilbert curve and morton curve.

Comment: A space-filling curve does not generally optimize for cache efficiency.

Comment: High-speed memory integrated into or close to the CPU, contains recently-used areas of RAM for faster access.

Comment: That's another defintion then you asked in your question.